# iOS Setting up game credits and in app purchase?

Tags: ios

1. Looking on how to set up a simple ios app that generates a random number 1-10 and will pay credit to the users bank if the user picks the right number.
2. How do I set up bank so users can buy more credits to play?

I am really new to all of this so any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Checkout this duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178214/ios-in-app-purchase-sample-code). Also, don't forget to read [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exceptionally broad question Vincent, and usually questions here need to be a lot more focused.

But I'll throw you a few keywords to get started:

In general, you should learn how to use [In-App Purchasing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which utilizes [Store Kit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html) in depth.

And, if you want your "bank" (hopefully virtual) to be shared with other players, check out [Apple's "Game Kit" solution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/).